# Spring returns NullPointerException when using @Injected class from jsp cewolf tag lib

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc, cewolf

I'm quite new to Spring and this is confusing me. I try to inject my DAO implementation and it works in controller class, but in another class I get NullPointerException when using exactly same code.

```
@Inject
private ResultCsvDAO res;
.
.
List<ResultRow> list = res.readResultToObjects();
```

The last row gives the NullPointerExceprion.
I have all used packages in the Spring config file.

```
<context:component-scan base-package="ptra.freecharts, ptra.controller, ptra.dao" />
<context:annotation-config />
```

Any ideas what I'm missing or doing wrong?

EDIT. This is full class

```
package ptra.freecharts;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import javax.inject.Inject;

import org.jfree.data.xy.XYSeries;
import org.jfree.data.xy.XYSeriesCollection;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import ptra.dao.ResultCsvDAO;
import ptra.model.ResultRow;
import de.laures.cewolf.DatasetProduceException;
import de.laures.cewolf.DatasetProducer;

@Service
public class DataProviderXY implements DatasetProducer, Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 4755020363939818521L;

    private final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(DataProviderXY.class);

    @Inject
    private ResultCsvDAO res;   

    public String getProducerId() {
        return "ptra.freecharts.XY";
    }
    public boolean hasExpired(
        Map arg0, Date arg1) {
        return false;
    }
    public Object produceDataset(Map arg0) throws DatasetProduceException {
        XYSeries dataset = new XYSeries("XY Dataset");      
        List<ResultRow> list = res.readResultToObjects();       
        for (int i=0; i<list.size(); i++) {
            dataset.add(i, list.get(i).getElapsed());
        }
        return new XYSeriesCollection(dataset); 
    }
}
```

EDIT 2. DataProviderXY is called in jsp:

```
<jsp:useBean id="dataXY" class="ptra.freecharts.DataProviderXY" />
<cewolf:chart id="XYChart" title="Transaction response times" type="xy">
    <cewolf:gradientpaint>
        <cewolf:point x="0" y="0" color="#FFFFFF" />
        <cewolf:point x="300" y="0" color="#DDDDFF" />
    </cewolf:gradientpaint>
    <cewolf:data>
        <cewolf:producer id="dataXY" />
    </cewolf:data>
</cewolf:chart>
<cewolf:img chartid="XYChart" renderer="cewolf" width="640"
    height="500" />
```

EDIT 3. I accepted Sotiros' answer, even tough there were others who were right too. Thanks for all of your help, I really appreciate it!

EDIT 4. I'm still struggling how to use Spring from jsp cewolf tag lib. Any pointers how to do it?

EDIT 5. I finally got it working. I followed Sotiros' answer "...through a @Inject point in a @Controller and add it to the Model."

Comment: Is that other class managed by the IoC container?

Comment: Note that `<context:annotation-config>` is redundant when using `<context:component-scan>`. Remove it.

Comment: Also show us where you are declaring and using the `DataProviderXY` bean.

Comment: Show us your `ResultCsvDAO` class.

Comment: @Bart The `ResultCsvDAO` class is irrelevant. If there was no registered bean, the context would complain.

Comment: I'm calling ResultCsvDAO class from jsp file

Comment: Show us where you are using the `DataProviderXY` bean. Where is it injected/used?

Comment: I edited original post again, piece of jsp is now there too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This element

```
<jsp:useBean id="dataXY" class="ptra.freecharts.DataProviderXY" />
```

**is completely unrelated to Spring.** The Servlet container (jsp tag lib) is creating an instance of the `DataProviderXY` class and using it. Spring can't inject anything if it never had the chance to process it.

If you are using Spring MVC, have the context provide you with a `DataProviderXY` either directly or through a `@Inject` point in a `@Controller` and add it to the `Model`.

Comment: This is probably true, even I don't yet fully understand how to do it. I'm using Spring MVC. I've to study a little...

Comment: I tried to follow this advice, but I'm still little lost. I injected DataProvider to my controller @Inject private DataProviderXY xy; and added it to my model and returned it to jsp return new ModelAndView("resultFront", "dataXY", xy); 
Any tips how to go further after this?

Answer (score 0):

What package is your `@Inject` annotation from?

Spring usually makes use of `@Autowired`, which is part of the Spring Framework API. Also `@javax.annotation.Resource` is processed by Spring Framework.

`@javax.inject.Inject` is only supported in Spring 3. Which version of Spring are you using?

If you're using Spring 3, you have to define a bean of type `ResultCsvDAO` inside your Spring container. This can be performed either in your XML Spring configuration file or using annotations, e.g. `@Component`.

Also, is this bean where you're trying to inject, a Spring-managed bean?

Comment: It's from the javax.inject package and preferred over @Autowired

Comment: It's from javax.inject.Inject. I get same problem when using @Autowired.

Comment: I might understood your question wrongly... The example code is used in 'ptra.freecharts' package.

Comment: We were saying about the `@Inject` annotation. What package is it from? Look at your `import` statements.

Comment: @AndreiNicusan It's better to annotate DAO classes with [@Repository](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/stereotype/Repository.html). It will make the annotated class eligible for Spring DataAccessException translation.

Answer (score 0):

Inversion of Control and Dependency Injection are Spring's core features. It guarantees auto injection and instantiation of dependent beans only if all the beans in the chain are managed by Spring.

To answer your specific problem, the class where you are injecting `ResultCsvDAO res;` is precisely not managed by Spring.

When I say managed by Spring, it means it must be instantiated by Spring and Spring must have information about this class.

If this still didn't help you then I believe you can paste the complete class and I will be able to resolve your issue.